# TestFlight vs Live - app crashing on load when Live but not in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have a strange problem with a number of my app users that I’m struggling to figure out.

I’ve had reports from a small portion of my app users that their app starts to crash when they open it. It shows the splash screen but as soon as it is about to engage the main form it crashes back to the home screen of the phone.

The strange thing is that the exact same build prior to submitting to Apple, if installed through TestFlight opens fine. As soon as an affected user then installs the exact same build from the Live Store over it, the app crashes on load again 100%

I’d like to understand what happens technically to an app binary when it transitions from TestFlight to Production in the Apple App Store and wonder if anyone knows?

This may be a red herring and no doubt it’s a bug in my code but I’m suspicious that TestFlight builds behave differently and I’d like to determine if it’s related.

Comment: It is simply re-signed.  If it is not happening to all your users who upgrade, it is not a code signing issue with the app being packaged for the App Store.  It is more likely a problem with your app.  Do you use CoreData?  Also, you need to get the crash reports and try to find the code that is crashing: https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/

Comment: Have you checked for any crash reports via Xcode, Go to Windows>Organizer>Crashes